# Overloading constructor duplicate

Tags: java, constructor

So, I'm learning java and I'm trying to make a class with multiple constructors, here are the classes

```
public class Chore {

    private String description;
    private int priority;
    private boolean completed;
    public Chore(int i; String s){
        this();
        priority = i;
        description = s;
        }
    public Chore(){

        String choreArr[] = {"Mow the lawn", "Fold the laundry", "Make dinner", "Vacuum the house"};
        int randChore = (int)(Math.random()*9);
        int randPri = (int)(Math.random()*10)-1;
        description = choreArr[randChore];
        priority = randPri;
    }
    public Chore(int i; String s){
        this();
        priority = i;
        description = s;
        }




}
```

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Chore c = new Chore();
        Chore d = new Chore(5 ,"Test");
    }
}
```

And I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
  The constructor Chore(int, String) is undefined
      at Tester.main(Tester.java:5)
```

Comment: That chore currently won't compile, parameters are split by `,` not `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
public Chore(int i; String s)
                  ^ must be comma, not semicolon
```

Also, you cannot have two methods (including class constructors) with the same signature:

```
public Chore(int i, String s) {
    //...
}
public Chore() {
    //...
}
//this one is invalid, remove it
/*
public Chore(int i, String s) {
    //...
}
*/
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent so much time reading and re-reading my code, how the hell did I not notice that. Btw I need both constructors, how do I fix it then?

Comment: @DanielFreire you cannot have two constructors with the same signature. This isn't possible in Java, even if the two constructors have different code in there. Note that you already have two constructors: one with no arguments and other with 2 arguments. What else do you exactly need?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two constructors with the same signature. And, the argument separator is a comma not a semicolon

```
public Chore(int i, String s){
  this();
  priority = i;
  description = s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have entered semicolon instead of coma...

```
public Chore(int i, String s){ 
        this();
        priority = i;
        description = s;
        }
```